# Cross Validation for GLM with fixed effects in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, fixed-effects-model

I was wondering if we can use k-fold cross-validation for model performance with a GLM-fixed effects model (fitted with the feglm function from the fixest package).

Comment: We can do cross-validation with GLM models, see R's [cv.glm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boot/versions/1.3-28/topics/cv.glm)

Comment: I am not sure that it can handle fixed effects (?).